# Unity Update() not called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Unity update doesnt work at all,

The gameobject is enabled

The script derives from monobehavior

Start() works normally

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace MouseStuff
{
    public class SetRotation : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Vector3 offset;
        
        public Transform lookObj;

        private void Start()
        {
            // This works
            print("Start");
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            // This Doesn't work
            print("Update");
            transform.rotation =
                Quaternion.Euler(Quaternion.LookRotation(lookObj.position - transform.position).eulerAngles + offset);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would doubt that .. sure that the script stays enabled and your script looks exactly like posted here?

Comment: Is the MonoBehaviour enabled? Is the game paused? Does another object with another MonoBehaviour get it's `Update` called? Investigate the issue.

Comment: Typically, it'd be wrong to mark any of those methods as `private`, but it doesn't matter in Unity since the methods are discovered via reflection when scripts are built. (That reflection doesn't happen in a build.)

Comment: @3Dave , I'm not sure if the best word if "wrong", but "you shouldn't do it", or, "if you're working on any large commercial team and you do that folks will laugh at you"  :)  Something like that.  The line between "wrong" and "bad form" is tricky in programming!!!

Comment: @Fattie I was trying to be nice. That was the best I could come up with. :D

Comment: methods not explicitly marked private are made private by the compiler.  so I do not think the problem the update method is marked private.

Comment: My guess is that an unhandled exception is being thrown and that causes the update() to no longer being called in future frames.  If you are still dealing with this issue and can look at the console output, that might be  a clue.

Comment: Had a similar issue. GameObject got disabled in Start() and that is why Update() wasn't called anymore.